# How to pass a function from outside of main component using react-redux's Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a main document:

```
<script>
    function fnc (param) {
        alert(param);
    }
     ReactDOM.render(
         <Provider store={store}>
             <App fnc={fnc}/>
         </Provider>,
         document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

App component has has children and grandchildren. Is there a better way to pass fnc to grandchildren (and perhaps get it via connect, similar to how reducers are mapped to props) so it can be called from there than passing it as a prop through all nested components at all levels (App -> children -> grandchildren)?

Comment: Higher Order Components [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) might help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React's context feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) can be used for this sort of thing.  In fact, it's what `react-redux` uses to get the store from the `Provider` to the `connect` function.

When dealing with context, it is usually best to, similarly to `react-redux`, use a provider component to add it, and a [higher-order component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to access it.

Provider:

```
import React from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

class FunctionProvider extends React.Component {
  getChildContext () {
    return {
      fnc: this.props.fnc
    };
  }

  render () {
    return React.Children.only(this.props.children);
  }
}

FunctionProvider.childContextTypes = {
  fnc: propTypes.func
};
```

HOC:

```
import React from 'react';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

function withFnc(WrappedComponent) {
  class WithFnc extend React.Component {
    render() {
      return < WrappedComponent fnc={this.context.fnc} {...props} />
  }

  WithFnc.contextTypes =  = {
    fnc: propTypes.func
  };

  return WithFnc
}
```

Add `FncProvider`:

```
function fnc (param) {
  alert(param);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <FncProvider fnc={fnc}>
      <App />
    </FncProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Wrap Component:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.props.fnc('test')}>Click Me!</button>
  }
}

export connect(mapStateToProps)(withFnc(MyComponent)
```

This might be a bit over the top though if you only need to pass it one or two layers deep and to a handful of components.  Sometimes `props` are a perfectly fine solution.

If you particularly wanted to use redux to solve this, you could create a middleware that calls `fnc` on a specific action (I'll use ES6 syntax for this because it's way cleaner, but let me know if you need it to be browser compatible and I'll add that too):

```
const fncMiddleware = (fnc) => (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type === 'CALL_FNC') {
    fnc(action.param);
  }
  return next(action);
}
```

The include the middleware when you create the store:

```
function fnc (param) {
  alert(param);
}

var store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(fncMiddleware(fnc)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now you can dispatch an action like `{ type: 'CALL_FNC', param='test' }` from you connected components like any other action.

Comment: Thanks! I like the approach with middleware, works lika a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Redux's `connect` is simply a [Higher Order Function](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that enhances your component by injecting redux's state into props (*mapStateToProps* is one example of it).

You can use the very same approach to pass your `func` only to specific components as you wish.

```js
const withCustomFunctionHOC = WrappedComponent => {
  const yourCustomFunction = () => alert('it works!')
  
  return (props) =>
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      yourCustomFunction={yourCustomFunction}
    /> 
}

const ChildComponent = ({ a, b, yourCustomFunction }) =>
  <div style={{ marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}>
    ChildComponent
    <div>Prop a: {a}</div>
    <div>Prop b: {b}</div>
    {yourCustomFunction
      ? <button onClick={yourCustomFunction}>I have customFunction (click me)</button>
      : <div>I don't have customFunction</div>
    }
  </div>

const EnhancedChildComponent = withCustomFunctionHOC(ChildComponent)
const App = () => 
  <div>
    <ChildComponent a={1} b={2} />
    <EnhancedChildComponent a={3} b={4} />
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```